# Filter columns by max values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing a SQL course, and I have the following table:

[image]

which I would like to filter its results ONLY if the latest timestamp and rating values are both the highest ones, for each player_store_id, so in this case, as expected result, rows 3 and 4 should be filtered.

How can I do it? tried with many different options, also searching, but didn't manage to make it work.

```
SELECT game_id, player_store_id, rating, timestamp
FROM #duplicated_reviews_date_and_rating
WHERE player_store_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT player_store_id FROM #duplicated_reviews_date_and_rating)
AND rating = (SELECT max(rating) FROM #duplicated_reviews_date_and_rating)
AND #duplicated_reviews_date_and_rating.timestamp = (SELECT max(#duplicated_reviews_date_and_rating.timestamp) FROM #duplicated_reviews_date_and_rating)
```

Only gives me the results for a single 'player_store_id'.

Everything I tried that I could find here, didn't work, gave errors, or was too complicated for my current level.

Thank you very much!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), which also applies to sample data and output. Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: *rows 3 and 4 should be filtered* - filtered in or filtered out? Prefer use of more specific other words like "included/excluded" or "present/absent"

Comment: *Only gives me the results for a single * - you'll need to coordinate the sub queries. `SELECT * FROM t t1 WHERE t1.x = (SELECT MAX(t2.x) FROM t t2 WHERE t2.y = t1.y)` is an example of a coordinate sub query. You want the max(x) per y, not the max(x) per the whole dataset, which is what you get when you omit a WHERE that references the table outside

Comment: When posing a mysql question always say what version; 5.7 is still popular alas

Comment: Is this MySQL? There are a few `#` in the query that makes me doubt that this is MySQL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use group by :

select player_store_id, max(myValue), game_id from table group by player_store_id, game_id;

Comment: Thank you. This did the job. Very simple.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an idea

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE myValue IN (SELECT max(myValue) From t);
```

Demo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6135ad/1

You can adapt it to your needs

Answer (score 0):

I Am not sure Whether I understand you question correctly.

You can try below Approaches. Below queries working fine in MS SQL Server. Please change the syntax according to MY SQL

Approch 1:

```
select * from 
review r
Join(
    select player_store_id,max(rating) rating,max(timestamp1) timestamp1
    from review
    group by player_store_id
) a
on r.player_store_id=a.player_store_id
and r.rating = a.rating
and r.timestamp1 = a.timestamp1
```

Approch 2:

```
WITH CTE
AS(
   SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  player_store_id ORDER BY RATING DESC,TIMESTAMP1 DESC) AS RNO FROM review
  )

  SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RNO = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the requirement is to get rows with timestamp and rating values that are both the highest ones, you can:

1. use a subquery to get the highest timestamp and rating for each group,
2. join with the original table to get the whole rows
3. on the condition that both its rating and timestamp are the highest for its group.

```sql
SELECT all_rows.*
FROM duplicated_reviews_date_and_rating all_rows
JOIN (
  SELECT max(rating) max_rating, max(timestamp) max_timestamp
  FROM duplicated_reviews_date_and_rating
  GROUP BY player_store_id
) highest
ON all_rows.rating = highest.max_rating
AND all_rows.timestamp = highest.max_timestamp;
```

Or even simpler, use an `IN` clause with multiple columns

```sql
SELECT *
FROM duplicated_reviews_date_and_rating
WHERE (rating, timestamp) IN (
  SELECT max(rating), max(timestamp)
  FROM duplicated_reviews_date_and_rating
  GROUP BY player_store_id
);
```

Demo: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3xy78e9x9